# Generate CSV from array of strings in Rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

In my controller, I'm creating an array of strings. I'd like to create a CSV which simply has each element of the array on a new line. They are already strings that are comma separated.

I've been trying to create the CSV file with this code in my controller:

```
#controller
@metrics = ["Group Name,1", "25", "44,2,5"]
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { send_data @metrics.to_csv, filename: "output.csv" }
end
```

And this code in my model:

```
#model
def self.to_csv(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    all.each do |row|
      csv << row.attributes.values
    end
  end
end
```

However, this outputs to my CSV file without the lines separated.

```
"Group Name,1", "25", "44,2,5"
```

The output I'd like to see is simply:

```
"Group Name,1"
"25"
"44,2,5"
```

Any thoughts on how to properly handle this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not at all clear what output you want, can you add that to your question so it's clear what you're trying to produce here?

Comment: Added some clarification on the output

Comment: That's not CSV, it's just a file with an individual string on each line surrounded by double-quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `@metrics` is an array, it doesn't look like you're calling any code on your model at all so your model code isn't actually doing anything.

This code your controller will generate the output you're looking for:

```
CSV.generate do |csv| 
  @metrics.each { |item| csv << [item] }
end
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but try formatting `@metrics` as an array of arrays: so each element of `@metrics` is its own array. It seems likely that `to_csv` treats an array like a row, so you need an array of arrays to generate new lines.

```
[["Group Name,1"], ["25"], ["44,2,5"]]
```

**UPDATE**

Looking at your code again, `@model` is not an instance of any model. It is simply an array. When you call `to_csv` on it, it is not reading any methods referenced in your model. I'm guessing that ruby's built in `Array` object has a `to_csv` method baked in which is being called and explains why you aren't getting any errors. @Anthony E has correctly said said this in his answer. (though I suspect that my answer will also work).

Comment: Yeah, that was my first assumption too. It should work but it doesn't process the inner arrays and tries to escape the strings: `"\"[\"\"one\"\"]\",\"[\"\"two\"\"]\",\"[\"\"three\"\"]\"\n"`